# Memorization of a recursive algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

Question: Given an amount `m` and an array of numbers `b[]` print `"Yes"` if `m` can be formed by addition of any number of elements from the array without repeating them.

This is what I've come up with; how can I add a memoization matrix into it?

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int check(int b[],int n,int m){ 
    if(m==0){
        return 1;
    }
    if(m<0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(n<=0 && m>0){
        return 0;
    }
    return check(b,n-1,m-b[n-1]) + check(b,n-1,m);
}

int main(){
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        int n,m;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        scanf("%d",&m);
        int b[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            scanf("%d",&b[i]);
        }
        if(check(b,n,m)>0){
            printf("Yes\n");
        }else{
            printf("No\n");
        }

    }    
    return 0;
}
```

**Can any one help me put a memorization matrix into it ?**

Comment: Do you mean *memoization*?

Comment: @Millie Smith, Caching the outputs by inputs to avoid recalculating them in later calls to the function. Perl example: `sub fact { my ($n) = @_; state $cache = [ 0 => 1 ]; return $cache->[$n] //= $n * fact($n-1); }`

Comment: @ikegami. Yeah, my comment is out of date. The question used to be "memorization of a recursive algorithm". Thank you though :).

Comment: @Kush M, The key to the cache consists of the first `n` elements of `b`, plus `m`. Form a string from these, and use it as a key to a hash table.

Comment: Sorry there is a typo in the question. the question should be,
"Memorization on a recursive algorithm"
Can anyone help me put a memorization matrix into it ?

Comment: I'm not sure you really mean memorisation or memoisation. They are related, but not identical. Please edit your question to be consistent **after** you checked ther meaning of the words. Also your question is too broad, we are not a coding site.

Answer (score 4):

The key to the memoization cache consists of the first `n` elements of `b`, plus `m`. Form a string from these, and use it as a key to a hash table.

...But what's the point? With `n` decreasing in each recursion, there are only two situations where memoization will help:

- When a non-recursive call `check` is made for exactly the same list of numbers and `m` as an earlier call to `check`.
- When `m-b[n-1] == m`, which is to say when `b[n-1] == 0`.

The first situation is unlikely (and decreasingly so as the size of the list increases, which is when memoization would help the most), and the second is easy to avoid. Just replace

```
return check(b,n-1,m-b[n-1]) + check(b,n-1,m);
```

with

```
return b[n-1] == 0
   ? check(b,n-1,m) * 2
   : check(b,n-1,m) + check(b,n-1,m-b[n-1]);
```